# How to make a django admin panel for a ready database?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, django-admin

how to make a django admin panel for a ready mysql database ?

I have a mysql database with tables and records in it , i want to make an admin panel for it how can i do that  ?

i searched and there was no strict answer for it .
any suggestions will be helpfull , thanks to this great community .

Comment: Did you try the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, If your connection with database is done then you can simple run this command in your terminal to generate **models** for your `models.py`:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

A new models.py file will be created on project level so you basically copy the code and save it in your `App/models.py`. Then run your migrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations app
```

Then

```
python manage.py migrate
```

After this you have to import all tables in your `admin.py` and register them like this:

```
from .models import *

admin.site.register(#modelname)
```

---

Run this command to download `mysqlclient` -    **`pip install mysqlclient`**

> Add This settings in your `settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'myproject',                        #<-- database name
    'USER': 'myprojectuser',                    #<-- database username
    'PASSWORD': 'password',                     #<-- database password
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',                             #<-- Change it port you're using
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i connect to mysql using django ?! i tried using mysql connector and wamp ? but everytime i get this error : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: @Moji.Michael i have updated the answer with required database settings.

Comment: should i install mysqlclient ? or any driver ? im using wamp server ? should i install visual studio build tools ?

Comment: Which os are you using?

Comment: im using windows 10

Comment: check the answer again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188332/discussion-between-ans2human-and-moji-michael).

Comment: i check the answer it asked me to install mysqlclient , and when i want to install mysqlclient it asked me to install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 . should i install visual studio ?

Comment: Welcome @Moji.Michael. #HappytoHelp